# Erro Laravel / linha 24

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com um problemao, com esse arquivo .Esse erro persiste apenas nessa linha,na maioria dos arquivos que abro da isso.
Eu queria poder saber oque exatamente errado para eu aprender e corrigir.

Da esses s[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]eguintes erro,e a linha do erro é extamente essa

CODIGO COM ERRO:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

CODIGO ATÉ UMA PARTE

```
<?php

/**

 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans

 *

 * @package  Laravel

 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>

 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Register The Auto Loader

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|

| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for

| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it

| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual

| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.

|

*/

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Turn On The Lights

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|

| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.

| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it

| will load up this application so that we can run it and send

| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.

|

*/
```

Comment: O Laravel por defeito utiliza a pasta public você parece estar a utilizar a pasta public_html

Comment: Porque está mexendo na pasta, nas configurações? Qual o motivo pertinente pra fazer isso?

Comment: Eu não estou mexendo,eu coloquei no local host,e esta apresentando esse erro,logo eu vi que seria essa linha

Comment: já executaste o comando `composer install`?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Antes de executar sua aplicação você deve instalar suas dependências, neste caso aparentemente falta instalar as dependências do composer execute `composer install` deverá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar? Achei que já estava configurado isso já. Essas dependências. Onde eu executo o composer install ? na posta do meus arquivos ou uma especifica?